# How should the payload look in Postman for a grpc request containing a timestamp

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "NotificationServiceServer";

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
package log;
// The greeting service definition.
service Notification {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SaveLogToRabbit (LogRequest) returns (LogReply);
}

message LogRequest {
  string serviceName = 1;
  string serviceMessage = 2;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp time = 3;
}

// The response message containing the greetings.
message LogReply {
  bool isSuccess = 1;
}
```

If I have such a protobuf file
how can I test my service via postman ?

```
{
    "serviceMessage": "tempor reprehenderit cupidatat nulla",
    "serviceName": "nisi ad sit",
    "time": "1696961114907"
}
```

I have also tried this 2023-10-10T12:00:00.000Z
and this

```
{
  "serviceName": "service",
  "serviceMessage": "message",
  "time": {
    "seconds": 1633824000,
    "nanos": 0
  }
}
```

While debugging I get the string values but the Time field is always null no matter what
[image]

The request itself comes with a null for the time property

Comment: If, as it appears, Postman is using JSON encoding of protobuf messages, then [`Timestamp`](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/#timestamp) should be RFC3339 (i.e. `2023-10-10T12:00:00.000Z`). You don't show the call you're making, the service's implementation or the result (errors). It's unclear how you conclude that the "Time field is always null no matter what".

Comment: I added a picture, but I don't see how the implementation of the service is relevant
One of the parameters, in the payload is missing even though I do send it, and I have provided how I send it(the payload of the Postman request)

Comment: The implementation is relevant because it helps diagnose the message that the server receives from Postman. In your image, you show the value of `stringRequest`, what is the value of `request`? It's possible that `JsonSerializer` is dropping the `Timestamp`.